# perforce depot not showing up on client using p4 depots

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-stream, p4java

I have recently migrated my perforce server from an older version running on windows to a new Server in Linux, using this [doc](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2538) as reference.

After restarting the server if i run `p4 depots` on my machine running the server, i get the following output

```
Depot depot 2017/06/05 local depot/... 'Default depot'
Depot spec 2020/05/20 spec .p4s spec/... 'Created by super. '
Depot streamsDepot 2017/06/05 stream 1 streamsDepot/... 'Created by perforce.  '
Depot unload 2020/05/20 unload unload/... 'Created by super. '
```

But when I run the same `p4 depots` command from a different machine connected to the server I only get the three depots

```
Depot depot 2020/05/20 local depot/... 'Default depot'
Depot spec 2020/05/20 spec .p4s spec/... 'Created by super. '
Depot unload 2020/05/20 unload unload/... 'Created by super. '
```

These are the same depots visible from p4v as well. Even after a 'Get Latest" click, I keep getting shown these 3 depots. I tried `p4 sync` as well , but again get errors along the line

```
//streamsDepot/... - must refer to client 'My-Client-Machine'.
```

Also , I do not see anything on `p4 depots` doc that solved my problem for me . Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons you might see different results from `p4 depots` commands from two different client machines (note that when you run a command "on the server" you're still using a client, the client just happens to be on the server machine):

1. You're connecting to two different servers.
2. You have two different sets of permissions.  (Depots you have no access to are hidden.)
3. (special exception for stream depots) You have a very old client executable and the server is hiding depot types that your client might not be able to parse.

`p4 info` will mostly let you rule out both of these.  If you're connecting to different servers, you'll see different `Server address` and/or `Server root` values.

If your `User name` is different that probably explains the permissions issue; if not, check the protection table for IP-based restrictions.   `p4 protects` may be useful here.

You can check the client executable version with `p4 -V`.

Comment: I can confirm that the server and the user are the same. Also the p4 protects and the permissions are all at default settings. Is it still expected to have any default IP restrictions as such? p4 -V on my system shows it to be 2019.2

Comment: Does `p4 protects` on the second machine show that you have access to `//streamsDepot/...`?

Comment: Never mind -- these aren't even the same server.  The timestamp being different on `depot` is a dead giveaway.  Almost fooled me!  :D

Comment: That was a silly error on my part, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: It's almost always the simplest possible thing, and you still always have to triple-check when helping someone else debug because they'll tell you they double-checked without actually doing it. ;)  I of course have also been guilty of this.